# NodeMCU with HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor

Tags: nodemcu, voltage-level, hc-sr04

How can I interface an ultrasonic sensor with a MCU with 3.3 V GPIO like the NodeMCU? I tried powering the sensor with both 5 V and 3.3 V from the MCU. Both failed to show any results as the distance appeared to be 0 V. In both cases the trig pin of the sensor was given 3.3 V input from the GPIO pin. I assume I need to level shift the echo pin output from 5 V to 3.3 V. How can I do that? Or is something else the issue? The code I used is fine as it works with Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet I found says the logic is TTL, which as far as I know is 2 V - Vcc, so 3.3 V should be fine. Is Trig just constantly given 3.3 V? According to the datasheet, it needs a 10 us pulse. Perhaps that is your issue? Code or schematics could help if that isn't it.

Comment: I have given trig pulse High and Low at 10us interval. The code is not the issue as I have used the same code with Arduino and it works fine.